# The title doesn't come to the starting position in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

```
var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            data: arrData,
            backgroundColor: ["rgb(41, 168, 124)",  "rgb(248, 167, 45)", "rgb(255, 58, 103)", "#8d8e94"],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ["rgb(41, 168, 124)",  "rgb(248, 167, 45)", "rgb(255, 58, 103)", "#8d8e94"]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        elements: {
            center: {
                text: total,
                color: '#26272A', // Default is #000000
                fontStyle: 'Pretendard',
                sidePadding: 60, // Default is 20 (as a percentage)
                minFontSize: 25, // Default is 20 (in px), set to false and text will not wrap.
                fontWeight: 700,
            }
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: titleText,
            align: 'start'
          }
    }
   
};

var ctx = document.getElementById(resultId).getContext("2d");
myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

I gave the title part an "align" start as follows.
However, the results are output to the center.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html

I think I did as it appears on the page, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: title and legend as plugins therefore starting form version3 they must be defined in the "plugins" configuration node. If you have a look to the documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html you posted, you can find: "Namespace: options.plugins.title"